# Avoid junk in the console buffer on win32

Tags: terminal, microsoft-windows, options

When I run vim in a win32 console window, after I exit I end up with a bunch of junk on the screen - old command output, etc, because cmd doesn't clear line contents when scrolling down. I've included an example below:

[image: Screenshot]

Is there a way to make vim clear the whole screen buffer (not just the part that is visible), either when starting it or on exit? Or to save the entire state (buffer contents, scroll position, and cursor position) and restore afterward?

Answer (score 1):

On further investigation, the `restorescreen` option was being set incorrectly in my vimrc.

I had this code (I don't know where I got it):

```
if exists(&restorescreen)
    if has("win32")
        set restorescreen
    else
        set norestorescreen
    endif
else
    set t_ti= t_te=
endif
```

but `exists(&restorescreen)` actually evaluates to 0.

Comment: Try `if &restorescreen` if you want tho check if `restorescreen` is set, or `if exists('&restorescreen')` if you want to find out if there is an option named `restorescreen` (but that should always return 1, since said option is always compiled in).

Comment: I think it was meant to detect older vim versions from before the option existed - I just took it out, I've been trying to clean up the version condition stuff in my vimrc since everything I use is on at least 7.2 now.